# My code is not working, Because I didnot know that i am comparing them wrong.

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and trying to learn it by my own. my code is not working. can anybody please help me find out the error.
Along with if anyone can tell me the best tutorials to learn java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class TwentyQue {

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    String first="", second="";
    String x="animal",vegetable,mineral;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("TWO QUESTION!");
    System.out.println("Think of an object, and I'll try to guess it.");

    System.out.println("Is it animal, vegetable, or minaral?");
    first=s.next();

    if (first==x){
        System.out.println("Is it bigger than a breadbox");
        second=s.next();
        if(second=="yes"){
            System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a mouse");
            System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a squirrel");
            System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");

        }

    }else if (first=="vegetable"){
        if(second=="yes"){
            System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a watermelon");
            System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a carrot");
            System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");

        }}else if (first=="mineral"){
            if(second=="yes"){
                System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a Camero");
                System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");
            }else{
                System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a paper clip");
                System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");

            }

        }




}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Any idea how can i acheive that?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Comparing String objects should happen using equals method. Ex :

> str1.equals(str2)

If you use == , then it would check if the references are equals or not and not the values

Answer (score 1):

Use `.equals(String s)` to compare strings' content, don't use `==`.

Use `==` only when you want to compare the identity of the object.

---

You can change the comparison of Strings to:

```
if (first.equals(x)){
  //...
}
else if (first.equals("vegetable")){
 //...
}
```

Apply the same for your other String comparisons.

Comment: You actually should be doing "vegetable".equals(first), this will prevent NPE when first is null.

Comment: @agilob - That is nowadays considered an [antipattern](http://pushinginertia.com/2011/05/why-yoda-conditions-are-bad-and-usage-of-javas-final-keyword-is-good/).

Comment: i have tried that but the code below id not printing. if("yes".equals(second)){
    System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a mouse");
    System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon avoiding NPE's an antipattern? First thing I've heard of  it.

Comment: @ManojKumar What is your first and second input?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon SonarQube is more convincing for me than this blog https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1132

Answer (score 0):

the code worked when i did following changes. Thank you all for your help.

```
String x="animal";
    String y="yes";String x="animal";
    String y="yes";
if (x.equals(first)){

        if(y.equals(second)){
            System.out.println("My guess id that you are thinking of a mouse");
            System.out.println("I would ask you but i really dont care.");
        }
```

That would be greatly appreciated if someone can tell me why it was not working when i did not intilise the variables with the desired value?